# Did the prophecy in OP mention how to defeat Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

The prophecy in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* didn't mention anything about how to defeat Harry Potter, did it?

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/40895/4918 "Why must “either must die at the hand of the other for neither can live while the other survives”?"

Answer (score 5):

> The one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord approaches... born to those who have thrice defied him, born as the seventh month dies... and the Dark Lord will mark him as his equal, but he will have power the Dark Lord knows not... and either must die at the hand of the other for neither can live while the other survives... the one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord will be born as the seventh month dies....

The prophecy does not say how to defeat Harry Potter. It gives a description of *who* the person who can defeat The Dark Lord will be, but does not say *how* one or the other will be defeated, only that only one will survive.

The Dark Lord wanted the prophecy because Snape had only told him the first half of the prophecy, because that was all he heard, about somebody defeating the Dark Lord. So after Lord Voldemort failed, he wanted the prophecy so that he would *know the full text*.

Comment: So Voldemort just wanted to know that last bit of information; that only he or Harry would survive?

Comment: @Varkstar Voldemort wanted to know the full text of the prophecy after he failed to kill him in GoF so that he would know why he failed.

Comment: To put it another way, the rest of the prophecy wasn't actually particularly useful to Voldemort, *but he had know way of knowing that in advance*.

Comment: Yeah, Voldemort didn't realize that it was just a 'prophecy'. Turned it a big deal so he tried to kill Harry and accidentally passed a bit of his 7th soul, as well as some of his powers, Voldemort didn't realize it was all his fault that he dealt with the prophecy.