# What happens to a living Horcrux that reproduces?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

Related perhaps to the [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8549/is-a-living-being-a-poor-choice-for-a-horcrux) asking broadly why a living being would be a poor Horcrux choice, but more specifically: what would happen if it reproduced? Would the resulting baby have a piece of the Horcrux creator's soul? Would it trickle across generations like a carried gene? Or does the curse remain solely with the initial intended target?

Answer (score 10):

Nothing. A Horcrux is a piece of one's soul put into an object (or a living thing). When something reproduces, nothing happens to its soul, so I don't see how anything would be particular to its offspring, except for the fact they would be especially mean and annoyed, as a side effect of hanging around a horcrux all day. I don't think there is any canonical content to back this up, so if there is give me a heads up, but I'm coming from the definition of a horcrux: A piece of someone's soul which is broken apart from the whole and hidden inside something else (be it an inanimate object or a living being) in order to protect it from harm. By this definition, and the knowledge that a being doesn't "inherit" its parent's soul - since a soul isn't exactly a biological part of a being - we can say that nothing will happen to the horcrux or to its offspring.

Comment: I think this is a possibility; obviously, given we have no real text to prove one way or another, this is realistic. However, I feel like blood and love are two very common motifs throughout the series - Voldermort requires Harry's blood to come back in a solid form, and love is what saved Harry. I wonder if this would play a part in the Horcrux being passed.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I totally agree here. I'm with you by saying, that the Horcrux itself will not reproduce, but I don't think that nothing will happen att all. Let's take the example of Ron with the horkrux he's wearing around his neck. As he's wearing it for a longer period you can see that it has a bad influence on him. He's getting really annoyed and angry all the time. So I would say maybe it will not cause any physical damage or reproduce but we could think of a sort of mental damage that is caused. Just speculating here, no canonical reference (except the thing with Ron)

Comment: Bloodlines are definitely a big part of the Harry Potter, just ask Marvolo Gaunt. I think the fact that Harry became a Parselmouth by becoming Voldemort's Horcrux, and the fact that all the Gaunts were Parselmouths shows us that particular magic easily finds its way into your descendants. I don't see how being a Horcrux COULDN'T affect your offspring. I eagerly await more answers!

Comment: @Zanser1609, as I said, if there is some kind of result from being born from a horcrux, I'd think it would have to do with being exposed to it for much longer than anyone probably has ever been. So I'm with you on maybe some form of mental damage, but if you think about it, it is the sort of damage that might happen to someone who spent the same amount of time exposed to the horcrux. Then, again, maybe not. I think you have a valid point, but I don't think it would have to do with bloodline.

Comment: @SplittingAdam I think the effects the horcrux would have on the offspring wouldn't have to do with it actually being the offspring, but actually with the prolonged exposure to the horcrux. On the Parselmouth example, it is indeed shown to have some relation to bloodline, so it can be passed down. The reason I believe it was also passed to Harry, however, had nothing to do with that. It had to do with how much being a Parselmouth meant to Voldemort. It was actually part of who he was, and so it made it's way to being in his soul.

Comment: However, it can't go the opposite way: something which is part of your soul doesn't become part of your DNA (if that is the case). So even though Harry became a Parselmouth, I don't think he would ever be able to pass that down to his kids. Of course a horcrux's child wouldn't be a regular child. If some days of exposure acted like it did upon Ron, imagine what some months would do to a unborn - and then new-born - baby.

Comment: @Valerie
It is also important to mention that it was my intention to post this as a comment, rather than an actual answering (understanding my lack o canonical proof). However, I wasn't able to because of the 50+ reputation rule. I thought it was important to bring up, however.

Answer (score 2):

## The Horcrux itself would stay within the being it was sealed in.

A piece of soul, once bound to an object, is then dependent on that object and can’t live outside it or exist without that specific object which has become its enchanted body.

> “But my point is that whatever happens to your body, your soul will survive, untouched,’ said Hermione. ‘But it’s the other way round with a Horcrux. The fragment of soul inside it depends on its container, its enchanted body, for survival. It can’t exist without it.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 6 (The Ghoul in Pyjamas)*</sup></sub>

A Horcrux bound to a living thing would work in the same way, so the piece of soul would therefore have to remain in the original living being it was sealed in - it can’t transfer to its offspring. Though it’s possible being born of a Horcrux may affect the offspring in some way, it won’t be by transfer of the soul piece or part of the soul piece, because it’s bound to and dependent on the original being.