# Why didn't Voldemort make a Dementor a living Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux, dementors

We know that Dementors are not immortal creatures, they cannot die as per se, but we know by fact that they can diminish by not sucking fear and souls out of people.

Even though, they are still pretty difficult to destroy and it would be one of the best choices Voldemort would have as a choice for a Horcrux. Is there any evidence in the HP world or any other Potterverse that would give a hint or suggest as to why this didn't happen?

Comment: Related, if not dupe: [Is a living being a poor choice for a Horcrux?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8549/98028)

Comment: A Horcrux contains a part of your soul.  *Dementors eat souls.*  Not even Voldemort is quite *that* stupid.

Comment: It is made pretty clear in the 6th and 7th book why Voldemort chose the objects that he did. It had little to do with making the strongest possible horcruxes. If you haven't read the books, I think I've seen plenty if questions about his choices here, many with great answers. Could you establish that you've checked some of them and that you still wish to ask your question since you think the answers don't apply to not choosing dementors?

Comment: Voldemort styles himself as the heir to Slytherin, wizarding nobility of the highest order. Placing his soul into a tin can, a shoe or a Dementor, while being eminently sensible is an utter perversion of everything he believes about himself. His royal soul needs to go into royal objects.

Comment: Possible dupe of [Why didn't Voldemort hide his Horcruxes in impossible-to-reach places?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/why-didnt-voldemort-hide-his-horcruxes-in-impossible-to-reach-places)

Comment: Valorum and Raditz make some excellent points. I have just one thing to add. The question here is- Can living beings without souls be turned into Horcruxes? Note that when the killing curse backfires, Voldemort's piece of soul blasted apart latches onto quote "the only living soul left" in that building. Maybe when we talk of living things to turn into horcruxes, they need to have souls. And Dementors are not inanimate, but not exactly living. Maybe the Ford Anglia can be compared in this context.

Comment: @Valorum after editing it you still think its  a dupe or primarily opinion-based?

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog - It's gone from opinion-based to a direct dupe of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/why-didnt-voldemort-hide-his-horcruxes-in-impossible-to-reach-places) but Bella's response (below) is actually a better answer. Probably best to merge them

Comment: @Valorum you call that a direct dupe? wow that came out of nowhere :p
srsly though, they are talking about same subject but this one is too specific to call it a dupe

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog - We normally choose the general over the specific. If we didn't, then we'd end up with endless variations on "*Why didn't Voldemort make x into a Horcrux"*.

Comment: @Valorum hahaha i thought that was the current situation going on :D :p

Answer (score 6):

## The Dark Lord used only objects he thought worthy as Horcruxes.

When choosing the objects that he’d use as his Horcruxes, the Dark Lord selected them carefully. As Dumbledore explained, he only used ones that he considered worthy of the honor of holding a piece of his soul, and typically they were objects that had a powerful magical history of their own.

> “Lord Voldemort liked to collect trophies, and he preferred objects with a powerful magical history. His pride, his belief in his own superiority, his determination to carve for himself a startling place in magical history; these things suggest to me that Voldemort would have chosen his Horcruxes with some care, favouring objects worthy of the honour.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 23 (Horcruxes)*</sup></sub>

As Valorum mentioned in the comments, Dumbledore knew Tom Riddle as well as it’s possible to know anyone, so Dumbledore is almost certainly right about the reasons behind the Dark Lord’s choices. It’s unlikely that the Dark Lord would consider a Dementor worthy of making one of his Horcruxes - they don’t have their own place in magical history, like the Founder’s objects, nor do they have any significance to him personally, like his diary and Nagini both did - and the Founders’ objects would as well because he felt the most at home at Hogwarts. A Dementor likely wouldn’t be something he’d think worthy, and because of that he wouldn’t want to use one.